# SwiftUI: Access @EnvironmentObject from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I want to use the **applicationWillTerminate** function to save some user defaults before the app closes. The data I want to save is stored in an **EnvironmentObject**.

How can I access it from the **AppDelegate** class?

Comment: You should throw the [SwiftUI] tag on this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `@EnvironmentObject` doesn't need to be instantiated directly in your SwiftUI objects; rather, it can be allocated somewhere else (for example, your UISceneDelegate) and then passed through using the `.environment(…)` function.

You could also allocate it on your AppDelegate, and pass that object though to your views in `UISceneDelegate.scene(_:willConectTo:options:)` method.

Paul Hudson has a good description of all of this at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Comment: In case someone needs code example for this answer.
class Test: ObservableObject{ }

------
in appdelegate:
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var myVar = Test()   }

 ------


  in SceneDelegate:

    
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        let myVar = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).myVar

        
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(myVar))

Comment: @Nalov you should post this as an answer so it's clearly formatted. This was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 5):

In case someone needs code example for this answer.

1.Create class that conforms to ObservableObject

```swift
class Test: ObservableObject{ }
```

2.in AppDelegate.Swift declare var myVar = Test()

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var myVar = Test()

    //****
}
```

3.in SceneDelegate.swift in "if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {" change the code like this :

```swift
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {

    let myVar = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).myVar
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(myVar))
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```